# In Raphael SVG, does translating a path mean "move the center" not "move the origin"?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Here's the code:

```
Raphael('holder', 400, 400, function() {
    this.circle(200, 200, 100)
    this.circle(200, 200, 140)

    this.circle(0, 0, 1).translate(300, 200).scale(10).attr({fill: 'green'})
    this.circle(300, 200, 5).attr({fill: 'red'})
    this.path('M300,200 L400, 200').attr({stroke: 'red', 'stroke-width': 3})
    this.path('M0,0 L1,0').attr({stroke: 'blue'}).translate(300, 200).scale(100, 100)
})
```

Here's the result in Chrome:

[image: Here's the result in Chrome]

Notice that the blue line's `M0 0` is not at 300,200!

What I expect is that the two paths would be coincident. When I `translate(300, 200)` I expect that `M0, 0` will place the pen at 300,200. But it doesnt! It places the pen somewhere else such that the center of the resulting path winds up at 300,200.

So, how can I make a path and position it's `M0 0` absolutely within the paper?

(Or, do I have to compute the center of my path and offset all the path values by that center? Please do not say "yes")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `.scale(100, 100)` on your blue line which resizes the whole line horizontally in both directions FROM the center point of (300, 200);

Simply exchange your last line with:

```
this.path('M0,0 L100,0').attr({stroke: 'blue'}).translate(300, 200);
```

to have the blue line cover the red one

Here is a fiddle for the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/QfAsY/

Answer (score 1):

[You can scale with a center](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.scale), so `scale(100, 100, 0, 0)` is the solution.